# Why is ubuntu package search severely outdated?

Tags: 14.04, package-management

at https://packages.ubuntu.com/, users can perform searches for ubuntu packages and source packages. but the content returned by server is severely outdated, for example, searching for package `linux-image-extra` in `trusty`(which is codename for 14.04) in the website shows the newest entry:

```
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic
```

at the same time using `apt search` inside of a ubuntu 14.04 distribution returns more recent results, the newest of which is:

```
linux-image-extra-3.19.0-80-generic
```

Why? Is that website not maintained anymore?

---

EDIT: To clarify I used `linux-image-extra` as search term intentionally to get newest possible `linux-image-extra-{VERSION}-generic` package version.

Comment: It's also probably useful to know about the kernel release schedule https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support, it looks like you may have installed a point release which uses a later kernel. Hence 3.19 as the kernel version instead of 3.13 which is the original still supported kernel for 14.04.

Comment: @Arronical, so are you saying the apt search result is tailored against my current kernel version?

Comment: There is no `linux-image-extra` package, so it can't possibly show you the latest version of it. All the `linux-image-extra-***-generic` are different packages, and it is showing you the latest version of each.

Comment: And if you want to obtain a list of all packages whose name matches some keyword even when there are very many of them, packages.ubuntu.com is not the right tool for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if the apt search result is tailored to your kernel version. Mine certainly isn't, it lists all kernel version for 3.13 (which I'm using), 3.16, 3.19, 4.2 and 4.4.

Comment: @fkraiem I'd be delighted to hear what may be the right tools.

Comment: Well it looks like `apt search` works pretty well, does it not?

Comment: @fkraiem I was trying to avoid search inside of a live system. preferring an web based api of the sorts.

Answer (score 3):

Your search was too vague. Right at the top of the results is this message:

> You have searched for packages that names contain *linux-image-extra* in
>   suite(s) *trusty*, all sections, and all architectures. Found **95**
>   matching packages.
>
> Your keyword was too generic, for optimizing reasons some results
>   might have been suppressed.
>   Please consider using a longer keyword or more keywords.

Just by adding [a `3.19` to the search terms](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-image-extra%203.19&searchon=names), I get:

> You have searched for packages that names contain *linux-image-extra*
>   *3.19* in suite(s) *trusty*, all sections, and all architectures. Found **36** matching packages.

Including this:

> [image: Package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-80-generic]

---

If you want to see the kernel releases available, try searching [`linux-image lts` for 14.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-image%20lts&searchon=names), or [`linux-image hwe` for 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=linux-image%20hwe).

Comment: You can have this one ;-)

Comment: I use this vague search term intentionally, as I wanted to search for a newest `linux-image-extra` available for `'trusty'` distribution. why would they not showing results for 3.19 just because the search is fuzzy?

Comment: @Sajuuk "for optimizing reasons some results might have been suppressed."

Comment: @muru are you suggesting even the count `95` is the count after suppressing?, I must say this is a highly confusing search experience.

Comment: @Sajuuk why would you think that? The page certainly doesn't show 95 results. There are 95 results in all, and some have been suppressed in the output.

Comment: @muru believe me I counted ( by copying them to a text editor ), it has 95 different package names.

Comment: @Sajuuk Ah, I made a mistake in my search. Then you're right, those 95 results are after suppressing. Either way, the answer doesn't change: use different search terms.